# What voxel rendering technique is used in Build engine games and how can I replicate that in another engine such as Unity or Godot?

Tags: unity, godot, voxels

Most information on voxel rendering is focused on heightmaps, but with my current understanding I dont see how one could achieve details like holes using a heightmap. In the below photo: details such as cheese hanging off the edge of a burger patty can be seen. To my assumption this means that the format used for these models is a point cloud or perhaps uses a series of cross sections.

If I wanted to achieve the same in an engine that doesn't already support these voxel formats where would I start?

[image]

Comment: What you've shown here look more like 2D pixel art sprites, not meshes, voxels, or point clouds. Do you have an example of these items in motion where we can see them from multiple angles? Or a source for these assets so we can look them up and examine them in detail?

Comment: Sure thing, upon research to find these voxels in a video, I discovered they are made using Ken Silverman's slab6. https://twitter.com/i/status/1410455636437991424

Comment: If that answers your question, want to document what you've learned in an Answer below? If not, want to edit your question to include this discovery and focus on what you still need help with?

Comment: I've begun trying out slab6, but I still have to grasp the basics of this program so I'll return to update this post by the end of the day.